# Rendering in Google Colab gone wrong

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am a newbie Blender user. I made my first animation yesterday and tried to render it in Google Colab. I ran a code which worked for a Youtuber who is running Blender2.91-linux version, but the same code showed error when I ran it.

I am currently using Windows 10 and really new at Blender. I need a working code that can successfully render Animation made with blender in Colab.

This is the code that I found online and ran. Please help :(

```
#Download Blender from Repository
!wget http://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.93/blender-2.93.0-linux-x64.tar.xz

#Install Blender
!tar xf blender-2.93.0-linux-x64.tar.xz

#Connect Google Drive
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/gdrive')

#Set Paths to Blender files
filename = '/gdrive/MyDrive/SHIP IN WATER With Particles.blend'

#Render an animation
!sudo ./blender-2.93.0-linux-x64/blender -b $filename -noaudio -E 'Cycles' -o '//image_####' -s 0 -e 72 -a -- --cycles-device OpenCL

The output of the last line came :
sudo: ./blender-2.93.0-linux-x64/blender: command not found
```

In short, I want a working code that can help me render Animation made in Blender in Google Colab.
Thank you in advance.... :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that the folder name is not the same after extracting from the tar file. Here is what you can do to fix your issue:

```
#Download Blender from Repository
!wget http://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.93/blender-2.93.0-linux-x64.tar.xz

#Install Blender
!tar xf blender-2.93.0-linux-x64.tar.xz

#Connect Google Drive
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/gdrive')

#Set Paths to Blender files
filename = '/gdrive/MyDrive/SHIP IN WATER With Particles.blend'
```

After that, add this command: `!ls` – you will get list files and folders in the current directory. Copy the extracted folder name from there and replace the old folder name with it:

OLD

> ./blender-2.93.0-linux-x64/blender

NEW

> ./NewFoldeName/blender